# How to run TopoJSON on Mac?

Tags: node.js, topojson

I need to bind a CSV file to topojson. I installed Node js with brew.

I can successfully run the command `npm install -g topojson` but when I put in `which topojson`, it doesn't return any file path.

I checked to confirm I have the command line tools installed and I do.

My command to bind the CSV returns `-bash: topojson: command not found` even though the npm install -g topojson command runs smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

`topojson` package installs five executables: `geo2topo`, `toposimplify`, `topomerge`, `topo2geo`, `topoquantize`.

Getting `command not found` for trying to execute `topojson` is the normal response: indeed, such an executable does not exist.